# Photos and videos vanished from "second space" on Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro

Tags: sd-card, xiaomi, redmi, parallel-apps

I have (for 2 years) the "second space" in use (Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro, MIUI 12.5.8.0 RJZEUXM, updated about 1 year ago), and it works wonderfully - two separate phones in one. But because I couldn't use the SD card in the second space and so lack of memory, I finally mounted the card as shared memory the week before last. Yay! Much more memory! But, a few days ago, the system deleted all pictures and videos in the second space that I had made since then (kayak tour). But only in the second space; the ones in the "first phone" are all there.

I hadn't changed anything before, no reboot either (except after the incident, but I didn't do anything). Various undelete apps found nothing; the memory card can't be it. Took a media scan also, but nope.

So:

1. How could this happen on the part of MIUI and
2. How can I (maybe, hopefully) get my pictures and videos back in second space?

Answer (score 0):

Xiaomi has sent out a mail to its users advising them on the closure of the cloud service for gallery items:

> Dear Xiaomi Cloud user,
>
> We're in the process of terminating cloud sync services for Gallery
> items. To avoid losing any of your data, we recommend following the
> instructions below to transfer or download your Gallery items as soon
> as possible.
>
> 1. Transfer items stored in the cloud to Google Photos
>
> First, make sure that your Gallery app is updated to the latest
> version (3.4.9.8). In the app, tap the dialog on the Start page or the
> notice at the top of the screen to start the transfer process, then
> follow the instructions. You can back up all your photos and videos to
> Google Photos.
>
> 2. Download items stored in the cloud to your device
>
> In your browser, visit i.mi.com, then tap the Gallery icon or select
> the dropdown menu next to your profile photo. Follow the instructions
> on the screen to download your items.
>
> Please note that you can only choose one of the above options.
>
> As of July 31, 2023, we will cease to offer transfer and download
> services for Gallery items, and any remaining Gallery items stored in
> Xiaomi Cloud will be permanently cleared. For more information on the
> specific service termination timeline in your region, visit:
> https://i.mi.com/announcement/stop_service?_locale=en_US